# How to keep search working on modified render columns DataTables.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I keep the lookup working on the DataTables.js modified render column?

In the snippet below, I tried to search the data that is in the **render columns** does not show anything.

```js
$('#release-table').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                autoWidth: true,
                ajax: "http://localhost/project/ajax/index_data.php?page=release",
                order: [[ 0, 'desc' ]],
                columns: [

                    { data: 'no', name:'id', render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                    }},
                    
                    { "data": 0 },
                    { "data": 1 },
                    {
                        "data": null,
                        "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                            return '<img src="http://localhost/project/assets/dashboard/files/'+row["2"]+'" width="40" height="40">';
                        }, searchable: true, orderable: true
                    },
                    {
                        "data": null,
                        "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                            return '<a href="http://localhost/project/dashboard/release/detail?id='+row["3"]+'" target="_blank"><span><strong>'+row["4"]+'</strong></span></a>&nbsp;<br><strong class="text-muted">'+row["5"]+'</strong>';
                        }, searchable: true, orderable: true
                    },
                    { "data": 6 },
                    {
                        "data": null,
                        "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                            return '<i>UPC: '+row['7']+'</i>&nbsp;<br>ISRC: <i>'+row['8']+'</i>';
                        }, searchable: true, orderable: true
                    }
                ]
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar issue and could not find a better solution than to add the search data in the column render inside an html element with `display:none;` in addition to what you are already rendering.

For example :
`<span style="display:none;">${data.property_1} ${data.property_2}</span>`

There might be a better solution to this, consider it more like a workaround, but it works.

Comment: I tried it doesn't work, I searched one of the data still empty